# NG Repeat with filter on list length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS NG-Repeat directive. I am using a object which looks like this.

```
{
    "filters": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "1207700620",
                      "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "1207825584",
                     "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "1207969166",
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Empty",
            "items": [] // This record must be ignored
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using below code to utilize ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="filter in myData.filters"> 
       {{filter.name}}
```

**problem**: I want to show only those records (name ) where items arrays length is > 0. How can I apply filter for same??

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing it:

on the html page:

```
<li ng-repeat="filter in myData.filters | filter: filterOnLength">
```

In the controller, added a function by name `filterOnLength` and in controller:

```
$scope.filterOnLength = function(item){
              return item.items.length > 0;
      }
```

Comment: I have exactly the same situation as yours, and used your `filterOnLength` to solve it.